# Как сделать проверку, если юзер создал новое поле Options то достать старое значение из localStorage и дописать к нему новое

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```
let newOption = new Option(newExerciceInput);
selectExercice.append(newOption);
selectExercice.value = newExerciceInput;



const arrayOptions = {
  exercises: [selectExercice.value]
} 

let selectExerciceJson = JSON.stringify(arrayOptions);
localStorage.setItem("isSavedNewUserExercice", selectExerciceJson);
console.log(selectExerciceJson);

let selectDataFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("isSavedNewUserExercice" );

if (selectDataFromLocalStorage) {
  let parseSelec = JSON.parse(selectDataFromLocalStorage);
  
  console.log(parseSelec);
  
}
```

Comment: setItem ты уже умеешь. Теперь используй ещё и getItem

Comment: Так я же использую getitem

Comment: Тогда не ясно что значит 'как дописать к нему новое'...... достал....проверил....записал

Comment: Я не пойму как сделать что бы этот объект постоянно пополнялся новыми свойствами

Comment: достал....проверил....добавил....записал......ты уже три из четырёх пунктов делаешь.... так что не ясно 'как сделать пополнение' .....пополнение делай после проверок.....если есть - добавить, если нет - создать объект и добавить

Comment: По логике всё понятно, проблема с записью,  запутался что и куда записывать.